# In NativeScript with Angular, how can I get an interface element the id?

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to avoid unexpected behavior in a NativeScript application.

When I walk into any screen that has a search field (SearchBar) system puts the focus on the search field automatically.

Then I got help with a friend who gave me a function to solve this problem. But the problem I'm facing right now is that I can not get the interface element. I have the following code:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {Page} from "ui/page";
import frame = require("ui/frame");

@Component({
    selector: "clientes",
    templateUrl: "pages/clientes/clientes.html",
    styleUrls: ["pages/clientes/clientes.common.css",
    "pages/clientes/clientes.css"]
})

export class ClientesPage {

    page;

    constructor(private _router: Router) {
        this.page = <Page>frame.topmost().currentPage;
        this.removeSearchFocus();
    }

    removeSearchFocus() {
        var parent = this.page.getViewById('box-lista');
        var searchBar = this.page.getViewById('barra-busca');

        console.log(JSON.stringify(parent)); // UNDEFINED
        console.log(JSON.stringify(searchBar)); // UNDEFINED

        if (parent.android) {
            parent.android.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            parent.android.setFocusable(true);
            searchBar.android.clearFocus();
        }

    }
}
```

And then I have the template:

```
<Page.actionBar>
    <ActionBar title="Clientes"></ActionBar>
</Page.actionBar>

<StackLayout orientation="vertical" id="box-lista">
    <SearchBar hint="Buscar" cssClass="mh mv" id="barra-busca"></SearchBar>
</StackLayout>
```

My goal is to get the auto focus of the search field, but I can not get the interface element.

Comment: Please ignore the "private _router: Router" inside the constructor.

Answer (score 11):

to expand on Nikolay's answer above this to use `@ViewChild` add #foo to your stack layout so it looks like:

`<StackLayout #foo ....`

then:

```
@ViewChild('foo') stackLayout: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    let yourStackLayoutInstance = this.stackLayout.nativeElement;
}
```

it won't get the element by ID but this is the more ng2 way of interacting with elements and keeps your code more loosely coupled to the DOM.

Comment: I asked a similar question [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809113/in-nativescript-with-angular2-get-element-value) can u answer that

Answer (score 2):

To get element in your project you should use  `@ViewChild` decorator, which will help you to create new property that point at the `SearchBar`. In regard to that you could review my project [here](https://github.com/tsonevn/NSAngularAnimationTranslate) and also to review this article: [Building Apps with NativeScript and Angular 2](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-4.html#42-animations)