# document.getElementById is not working in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, nativescript

I am new to TypeScript and trying to create a simple app. Meanwhile I was trying to get the element value from HTML to TypeScript by using the `document.getElementById` method and it is throwing this error:

> Reference Error document is not defined.

I am using this code below:

```
<TextField hint="UserName" name="usernameID" id="usernameID" style="margin-top:5%"/>
```

and trying to get it in its TypeScript method:

```
export function onLogin() {

    var username = document.getElementById('usernameID');
    console.log('username :: '+username);
    frame.topmost().navigate("views/choicepage/choicepage"); 
}
```

I don't know what I am missing here.

Comment: Are you using angular ?

Comment: You're not using `document.getElementById`. You're using `document.getElementsByName` which is a different function and returns a NodeList. BTW, `TextField` is not a valid HTML element, so I'm not sure that it would work in any case.

Comment: No @saperlipopette , it's nativescript

Comment: Given that NativeScript doesn't use HTML, I doubt the `document` object is available in that environment (it'd have been helpful if you'd mentioned that was the framework you were using in your question).

Comment: Yes @JoeClay It is using it's own customized kind of XML. What is the another way to achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In NativeScript with Angular2, how can I get an interface element the id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884142/in-nativescript-with-angular2-how-can-i-get-an-interface-element-the-id)

Comment: It doesn't works @JoeClay , I have already gone through that question.

Comment: If you've got the frame, then you can get a view by its id. `frame.topmost().getViewById("viewId")`

Comment: Hi Guys..I was able to resolved that issue giving the page load attribute on the "Page" tag in the XML. And then created a method for PageLoaded which will be having the context of that page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to resolve that issue by adding the '**Loaded**' attribute to the "**Page**"and then created a method with the same name of the loaded attribute which will be having the context of the page. Below is the code.

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">
<!--
Stack layout for ordering the HTML element at the login page
-->
<StackLayout class="p-20" orientation="vertical">

    <!--Fields for getting the username and password for input-->
    <TextField hint="UserName" id="usernameID" style="margin-top:5%"/> 

    <TextField hint="Password"  id="passwordID" autocorrect="false" secure="true" style="margin-top:3%"/>

    <!--Login button here-->
    <Button text="login" tap="onLogin" id="logInButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-active" style="margin-top:5%"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

And here goes the TypeScript

```
import { EventData } from 'data/observable';
import { Page } from 'ui/page';
import { TextField } from 'ui/text-field';
import { Button } from 'ui/button';

let pageLoaded = (args : EventData) =>{
    let page = <Page> args.object;
    let textValue = <TextField>page.getViewById('usernameID');
    let logInButton= <Button>page.getViewById('signUpButton');

    logInButton.on('tap',(args:EventData)=>{
        console.log('textValue :: '+textValue.text);
    });
}
export {pageLoaded}
```

Thanks for your help guys...Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Nativescript don't know about document object its browser thing which not exists in android or ios apps done with Nativescript

Comment: then what we can use instead?

Comment: Depends on what you want to get as element @StanimirPetrov page method getViewById, checkout https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/basics#execute-business-logic

Answer (score 0):

Document doesnt exist in nativescript. You will either need to use `@ViewChild()` for angular or `this.page.getViewById` for vanilla

Comment: Hi @mast3rd3mon I am getting undefined when I am passing the Id in this.page.getViewById('IdName');

Comment: @TariqueShamim do you have a `*ngIf` on a ancestor element?

Comment: @NinjaOnSafari he isnt using angular